# Quartz job stops executing on StaleObjectStateException exception

Tags: hibernate, grails, exception, quartz-scheduler, grails-2.0

I have a problem with quartz ( plugin :quartz2:2.1.6.2 but I have test even with plugin :quartz:1.0-RC7 but the problem does not change) on my Grails Project ( grails 2.2.1 ).

I have a job like this

```
class MyJob {

def concurrent = false

def execute(context){

        try {

            //....
            // works with domains .....
            myDomain.save(flush: true)
            // works with domains .....
            //....

            sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()

        } catch (org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException olfe) {
            println "Job failed by database exception "
        } catch ( org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException ole){
            println "Job failed by database exception "
        } catch ( org.hibernate.HibernateException hibe ){
            println "Job failed by database exception "
        }
    }

}

}
```

Sometimes a StaleObjectStateException occour in the execute method. This is ok for my logic, I'm using grails optimistic locking and this exceptions occour only once a week.

The problem is when this exceptions occour the Job stops to fire again.

I have tried co wrap the method code in a try catch and flush hibernate session inside to capture the exception but without fortune. The exception is not capture by any of my catchs.

Looking online I found this an [old grails quartz bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPQUARTZ-35?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel) but it's fixed, and in any case using the try{}catch must bypass the bug.

P.S.
The job is scheduled from bootstrab by a call of this type

```
MyJob.schedule( 10000L )
```

The exception that stops the scheduling is

```
[194949896] core.ErrorLogger Unable to notify JobListener(s) of Job that was executed: (error will be ignored). trigger= DEFAULT.MT_3tbn6lewgiqa3 job= DEFAULT.MyJob
org.quartz.SchedulerException: JobListener 'persistenceContextJobListener' threw exception: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [MyDomain#42] [See nested exception: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [MyDomain#42]]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersWasExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1939)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyJobListenersComplete(JobRunShell.java:361)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:235)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [MyDomain#42]
    at grails.plugin.quartz2.PersistenceContextJobListener.jobWasExecuted(PersistenceContextJobListener.groovy:46)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersWasExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1937)
    ... 3 more

.....

events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [MyJob#42]
    at MyJob.execute(MyJob.groovy:354)
    at grails.plugin.quartz2.GrailsArtefactJob.execute(GrailsArtefactJob.java:57)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

Comment: in your code example your not catching 'org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException', so i guess it's normal the job fail...

Comment: @moskiteau org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException is a org.hibernate.HibernateException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for reviving an old post, but we encountered this issue with a legacy Grails app (Grails 2.2.3) recently and flushing the session in the execute method did not always solve the issue so I'll outline what we did to fix the problem.

In our case, sometimes the exception would happen outside the context of the execute method, even when we explicitly flushed the session within the execute method. More specifically, the exception is thrown within the Quartz2 plugin's PersistenceContextJobListener code that flushes the session AFTER the execute method was finished executing. So after reviewing the Quartz2 plugin code we realized that that we needed to override the default PersistenceContextJobListener that wraps the job execute method and flushes the session.

First, notice that there's no exception handling within the jobWasExecuted callback method of the PersistenceContextJobListener.

https://github.com/9ci/grails-quartz2/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/quartz2/PersistenceContextJobListener.groovy#L44

All you really need to do is implement your own job listener and wrap the jobWasExecuted code in a try/catch. See the following code snippets for an example of how to do this.

https://gist.github.com/jmiranda/45084eb32f07f6e3d1934547cd4fbb9f
https://gist.github.com/jmiranda/5148f0a67afc8950bad950793e9c2303

We used the original Quartz plugin's SessionBinderJobListener as an example (err, we more or less copied it).

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugins/quartz/listeners/SessionBinderJobListener.java

Anyway, this should get you to the point where you are preventing triggered jobs from stopping altogether due to the uncaught StaleObjectStateException.

Comment: Great work Justin. I'm not working on that project anymore and I cannot test the solution but seems good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how accurate your example is but you need to know that groovy is wrapping exceptions. This means that even, when code is thrwoing StaleObjectStateException, you could get it wrapped in simple RuntimeException which is not catched above. How deep is that `myDomain.save(flush: true)` method (straight in job or executed from other service)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, the quartz job runs on a thread which does not have a hibernate session bound to it, I was able to get around it by grabbing a new session and then forcing a flush() and a clear(). If you don't flush & clear the job will eventually re-use one of the previous job threads and attempt to write out the same object out(can't recall if it had to be the same or any object of the same class), but there will be an un-committed copy in the session bound to that thread, which will in turn cause a StaleObjectException:

Here is what my code looks like:

```
def sessionFactory

def execute() {
    def session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory,true)

    myDomain.save(flush: true)

    session.flush()
    session.clear()
}
```

You may just need to do the flush() and clear() in your example code to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanl you miedzial. Tried with flush and clear. The problem is not the StaleObjectException wich is assumed by my project. The problem is that when the StaleObjectException occour I was not able to catch it and the quartz stop executing other calls